# How can we upload an image in a JSP in a Spring MVC Hibernate application?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I need to save an image from jsp to database (MySql) in Spring MVC Hibernate web application.
Could somebody give me an example of uploading an image and then saving it into db ?

Answer (score 0):

use any of the jquery based fileuploaders , and save just the path in db. that way you will be able to scale your app fast.  e..g valum uploader

Answer (score 0):

Solution is first get path from jsp and with hibernet pass object as a parameter.

### UserVehicle.java

```
private byte[] image;
public UserVehicle(byte[] image)
{
  this.image=image;
}
---getter n setter
}
```

### in Controller.java

```
File file = new File(/*your file path*/);
byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
fileInputStream.read(bFile);
fileInputStream.close();
UserVehicle user = new UserVehicle(bFile)
```

your value will be inserted as blob file in your database.

Answer (score 0):

using the Spring MVC, so you can use spring form like this:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/spring-mvc-xml/uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="file">Select a file to upload</form:label></td>
        <td><input type="file" name="file" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

the most important part is to add the **enctype="multipart/form-data"** and the type of the **input must be** **"file"**, then you can add for your rest controller the multipart param like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, ModelMap 
modelMap) {
 // here u can find your uploaded file you can set the prop in your 
    object model ,then save object and this will save the file also in 
    blob.

return "fileUploadView";
}
```

finally you need to crate multipart Bean in your spring context like this:

```
//you can defined it in xml way if your configuration in xml file 

@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver()
{
 CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
   multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(20848820);
 return multipartResolver;
}
```

and also you need to add the upload file library at your dependency to Spring can use it :

```
dependency>
 <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
 <version>1.3.1</version> // or you can find the last version
</dependency>
```

last Note : for the data base you can set the column is BLOB or any LOB type.
I usually use this way to upload files in my Spring applications , so I hope that you are need also.